# How to call object methods inside a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript

How to call object methods inside a forEach loop?

this is the object containing functions that I;ve created

```
const functionCallLinks = {
data: () => item.data,
list: () => item.list,
}
```

Here I'm referencing some functions inside an object called functionCallLinks

```
const functionCallLinks = {
data: () => item.data,
list: () => item.list,
}

let mappings = {}

// see link()
Object.keys(functionCallLinks).forEach(link => mappings[link()] = 'true')

// note here i'm using link() for referencing the original key . ie either data() or list() from functionCallLinks
```

so in a similar manner can I reference the function inside the object functionCallLinks through and alias like link() so that I can free up some repetition?

**NOTE** note here i'm using link() for referencing the original key . ie either data() or list() from functionCallLinks

Comment: `link()` -> `functionCallLinks[link]()`

Comment: damn, removed my comment ... `link` is the key, so `link()` isn't a function, since an object key is always a string ... `Object.values(functionCallLinks).forEach(link ...` now you got some functions ... but then ... what do you expect `item` to be?

Comment: What's in `item`?

Comment: item is just something else... dont worry about  that..

Comment: the idea here is to return either item.data or item.list when i call either  functionCallLinks.data() or  functionCallLinks.list()

Comment: with that return value i can do somethink like this mappings[item.data] = 'true'